# Creating database with only ldf file created 2 .ldf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run this query without specifying the ldf file it automatically creates the ldf file.

```
Declare @DBname nvarchar(50) = 'Test'
Declare @path nvarchar(50) = 'D:\DB'
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

set @query = '

CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBname + '
ON
( NAME = ' +@DBname+',  
    FILENAME = '''+@path+'\'+@DBname+'.mdf'+''',
    SIZE = 1024,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 500 )  
'
exec (@query)
```

But when I run this query:

```
Declare @DBname nvarchar(50) = 'Test'
Declare @path nvarchar(50) = 'D:\DB'
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

set @query = '

CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBname + '
ON 
( NAME = '+@DBname+'_log'+',  
    FILENAME = ''' +@path+'\'+@DBname+'_log.ldf'+''',
    SIZE = 100,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 100 );
'
exec (@query)
```

It creates 2 .ldf file without .mdf file. I don't understand why it creates 2 .ldf file and not mdf file automatically as it did in the above query:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified ldf extension to the mdf file. It is still a data file. The log file is specified with '**LOG** ON', and the data file with 'ON', just like you did.

The actual log file specification is optional, and it is created by default.

Look at the syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted, when this is correct. Perhaps the downvoter could give their reason?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are naming in your SQL is the database file, **not** the Log file. Therefore you are creating an `mdf` file and giving it an `ldf` extension. Much like if you were to create a `xlsx` file but give it an extension of `csv`.

If you want to specify the details of the log file, you need to do so using the `LOG ON` syntax; as shown in the documentation [Creating a database that specifies the data and transaction log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-creating-a-database-that-specifies-the-data-and-transaction-log-files):

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE Sales
ON
( NAME = Sales_dat,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf',
    SIZE = 10,
    MAXSIZE = 50,
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )
LOG ON
( NAME = Sales_log,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\salelog.ldf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;
GO
```

In your case, this would likely result in:

```
DECLARE @DBname sysname = N'Test';
DECLARE @path sysname = N'D:\DB';
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @query = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBname) + N'
ON 
( NAME = N'  + QUOTENAME(@DBname, '''') + N',  
    FILENAME = N' + QUOTENAME(@path + N'\' + @DBname + N'.mdf', '''') + N',
    SIZE = 1024,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 500 )
LOG ON
( NAME = N'  + QUOTENAME(@DBname + '_log', '''') + ',  
    FILENAME = N' + QUOTENAME(@path + N'\' + @DBname + N'_log.ldf', '''') + ',
    SIZE = 100,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 100 );';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query;
```

Note that I have changed your data types to `sysname` and used `QUOTENAME` to avoid injection. If you are going to have a path **longer** than 128 characters this won't work; but I *assume* that is unlikely based on the example.

If you *do* have more than 128 characters use the syntax like the below for the path expressions.

```
N'...N''' + REPLACE({Your Path  Expression}, '''', '''''') + N''' ...'
```